# Creating a Torch/flashlight app for Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to create a Torch or flashlight app in Android which can turn on/off the back flashlight of device. I want to do it with this permission:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
```

I don't want to use **Camera** permission.
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: and why you don't like to use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity.